# viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array get category

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

i am a very practical civil engineer (very poor programmer). I want to detect objects on construction sites. Now i follow a tutorial and i get a picture with a bounding box with the detected object.
My question here is: How can i get a string with the category name, index or id?

[image]

with this code:

```
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=5,
            min_score_thresh=.6,
            line_thickness=10,
            keypoint_edges=4,
            agnostic_mode=False)


plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_np_with_detections, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same code, `print(category_index[detections['detection_classes'][0]+label_id_offset]["name"])` worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `category_index` variable as the following code:

```
PATH_TO_LABELS = './models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
# category_index is a dictionary as seen below:
# {1: {"id": 1, "name": "category1"}, 2: {"id": 2, "name": "category2"}}
```

Where the models directory refers to `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models`.

More help can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection).

Comment: Hey Paulo, thanks for the quick answer. I have created my own custom-made model with 2 categories (exit sign, fire extinguishor) that are not in the category_index you posted the code. 
Do you know how to get them?

Comment: `category_index` should be a dictionary like: `{1: {"id": 1, "name": "exit sign"}, 2: {"id": 2, "name": "fire extinguishor"}}`

Comment: Yes, i have that. But i want to print out as strings the categories that are detected in a picture. 
Do you know how to do that Paulo?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same question as this person: http://5.9.10.113/67451012/tensorflow-object-detection-api-print-detected-class-as-output

Comment: The only possible reason I can see is `label_id_offset`, try set `0`. If not even the box is showing, try lowering `min_score_thresh`. You can `category_index[detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy()]['name']` to get the name of the class (`[0]` may vary depending on the size and shape).