# TensorFlow 2 print object name if object is detected

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to write code using Tensorflow from tutorial for detecting objects with a camera, I want the detected object to print once as soon as it is detected.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.8,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Here are the names of my labels that have been learned

```
labels = [{'name':'phone', 'id':1}, {'name':'headphones', 'id':2}, {'name':'glasses', 'id':3}, {'name':'mug', 'id':4}]

with open(files['LABELMAP'], 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a very basic version of what you are looking for. It will print something if any of the images you have trained it to find, is detected. I'm going to look into seeing if I can find a more specific way of doing it, but I thought this would be helpful for now.

```
label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

if np.any(detections['detection_scores'] > 0.8):
 print("Object detected!")
   

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=5,
            min_score_thresh=.8,
            agnostic_mode=False)
```

[Update]: I found some code here: [viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array get category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566244/viz-utils-visualize-boxes-and-labels-on-image-array-get-category) by the user Johan David Lozano. I took that code and combined it with the code above. to get this:

```
print(detections['detection_scores'])
print(category_index[detections['detection_classes'][0]+label_id_offset]["name"]) 
if np.any(detections['detection_scores'] > 0.8) and 
category_index[detections['detection_classes'][0]+label_id_offset] 
["name"]=='Class1':
print('Object 1 found')
```

I believe this only works with 2 objects as I think [0] makes it look at the first number of the detection classes array and when you have 2 objects it will be 1 for one and 0 for the other.